# How to return a lambda that is returned by another method in Ruby

Tags: ruby, lambda

I tried this, but it does notwork.

```
def n_times(thing)
    lambda {|n| thing * n }
end

def other(counter,thing)
    com = counter(thing)
    return com
end

com = other(n_times,10)
com.call("what ")
```

error :

```
test.rb:1:in `n_times': wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) (ArgumentError)
    from test.rb:10:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`n_times` is a method requiring one argument, you are calling it as the first argument passed to `other`, but without an argument. That's the error you are getting. You want to pass `method(:n_times)` which converts it to a Proc rather than calling it.

Secondly you have `counter(thing)` inside the `other` method. This is calling the *method* called 'counter', rather than using the *object* called 'counter' which is passed as an argument. You want to change that to `counter[thing]`.

Lastly, you are passing 10 to `n_times` and calling the resulting lambda with "what", but that evaluates `10 * "what"` which is a NoMethodError. You need to reverse those arguments.

All together:

```
def n_times(thing)
  lambda { |n| thing * n }
end

def other(counter, thing)
  counter[thing]
end

other(method(:n_times), "what").call(10)
# "whatwhatwhatwhatwhatwhatwhatwhatwhatwhat"
```

Comment: I see,you mean there is no way to pass a tradition(defined by `def`) function to other function directly. Am I rigth?

Comment: You can. But, since parenthesis are optional in Ruby, `n_times` on its own is interpreted as a method call without arguments. If you want to refer to the method itself, you need to do it explicitly with `method(:n_times)`.